graph signal in the context of graph neural network
I am reading several materials about graph signal processing for a thesis on Graph Neural Network and i see that a graph signal is defined as a vector so each node signal is a scalar. In practice, a node usually has a vector as its feature so I am wondering how can the graph signal extend to that case. I would appreciate it if you can include references in your answer. One of the example material I am reading that include the graph signal definition is https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese2240/labs/1200_ch_9_signal_processing_on_graphs.pdf
